# Asp.net how to convert HTML page to PDF

Tags: asp.net, html, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I have read all the related links to this question but nothing show what i want :(
so i am asking :

Now i have a HTML page and i need to make a link or button to convert this page to pdf

so is there any **FREE dll** that i pass the HTML to it and it returns a PDF.

hint: i am using vs2010, MVC3.0, c#4.0

Comment: It's not a free dll, but if you want to give the client the ability to do this, I JUST read an article on a nice free option for doing this here:

 http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/products/review-joliprint-pdf-converter-bookmarklet/1596?tag=nl.e175

Answer (score 3):

Personally I am using the following [Java library](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) where I compiled the .jar into a .NET assembly using the [IKVM.NET Bytecode Compiler](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html).

Comment: i am not familar with java can u please send me .net assembly of this jar

Comment: @user626996, you don't need to be familiar with Java. You just need to download IKVM.NET and run the compiler which will generate the assembly.

Comment: I have tried ikvmc myProg.jar , first it gives me .exe not .dll so i cant include as a ref , second after i tried to run this exe it gives me some java errorssssssssssssss

Comment: You could specify the `-target:library` compiler switch.